# Injecting Mock service in AngularJS/ Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I'm using jasmine to test my controllers, which I wrote in TypeScript. My unit tests are in plain javascript.
I'm getting an error when I test my controller, where I want to inject a mock service.

This is how my test looks:

```
'use strict';

describe('ConfigCtrl', function(){
    var scope, http, location, timeout, $httpBackend, service;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('busybee'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $http, $location, $timeout, configService, $controller){

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        http = $http;
        location = $location;
        timeout = $timeout;
        service = configService;


        $controller('configCtrl', {$scope: scope, $http: http, $location: location, $timeout: timeout, configService: service});
    }));

    it('should have text = "constructor"', function(){
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

My app.ts:

```
module game {
    'use strict';

    var busybee = angular.module('busybee', []);
    busybee.controller('configCtrl', ConfigCtrl);

    busybee.service('configService', ConfigService);
    ...
    ...

}
```

and my TypeScript controller:

```
module game {
    'use strict';

    export class ConfigCtrl {

        static $inject: string[] = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', 'configService'];

        constructor($scope: ng.IScope, $http: ng.IHttpService, $location: ng.ILocationService,
            $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService, configService: game.ConfigService) {  
            //any code here
        }
    }   
}
```

When running karma, I get the following error:

```
Chrome 28.0.1500 (Linux) ConfigCtrl should have text = "constructor" FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
            at Object.instantiate (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:28:283)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:28:494)
            at Object.d [as invoke] (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:28:174)
            at /home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:29:339
            at c (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:27:13)
            at Object.d [as invoke] (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:27:147)
            at workFn (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular-mocks.js:1778:20)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at Object.window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject [as inject] (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/libs/angular/angular-mocks.js:1764:25)
            at null.<anonymous> (/home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/test/ConfigCtrlSpecs.js:9:29)
            at /home/david/git/busybee2-client/js/test/ConfigCtrlSpecs.js:3:1
Chrome 28.0.1500 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.329 secs / 0.032 secs)
```

It seems, there's a problem injecting the `configService`, but I don't have an idea why.

**EDIT**: added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q552U/6/

**UPDATE**: It seems it was a problem for jasmine having the compiled javascript of the TypeScript classes in different files. Compiling the TypeScript files to a single .js file (`tsc --out dest.js source.ts`), does it for me.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of the code with tests so everyone can take a look at it? (since not many people are using TypeScript so fiddle may help to debug.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try get the service using `$injector`.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $http, $location, $timeout, configService, $controller, $injector){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    http = $http;
    location = $location;
    timeout = $timeout;
    service = $injector.get('configService'); //not sure the name, you may try 'ConfigService' as well.

    $controller('configCtrl', {$scope: scope, $http: http, $location: location, $timeout: timeout, configService: service});
}));
```

Link to [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hepcv/).

Comment: Link to Demo throws a 404

Answer (score 4):

Nice answer from zsong, but that code can be updated further by removing `configService` from `angular.mock.inject()` as it is not necessary.

Another possibility is to write your test in TypeScript (and use Jasmine type definitions), which is a cleaner way to do it. In that case, your test will look like this:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

describe('ConfigCtrl', () => {
    var configCtrl, scope, http, location, timeout, configServiceFake;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('busybee'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(($rootScope, $http, $location, $timeout, configService) => {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        http = $http;
        location = $location;
        timeout = $timeout;
        configServiceFake = configService;

        configCtrl = new game.ConfigCtrl(scope, http, location, timeout, configServiceFake);
    }));

    it('should have text = "constructor"', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```